# Is there a technical difference when discarding an exception variable?

Tags: c#, exception

At some point during my career i learned that there is a major difference between doing

```
throw e
```

and

```
throw;
```

(The first version mangles the stack trace to be incomplete).

Is there a noteworthy difference between

```
catch(FormatException)
```

and

```
catch(FormatException e)
```

as well, which has a significant difference? (Apart from no option to hover an exception when debugging)

I am wondering if there is some technical reason to do this, because yesterday i noticed in some github repo (dnSpy), that the developer discarded the variable. I hope the answer to this is more exciting than "no - it's just shorter to write if you're not interested in the exception"

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Not declaring the variable will catch that specific type of exception, but won't examine the exception details in any way.  And of course having an unused variable would generate a compiler warning.  The only technical difference really is whether or not the exception object is assigned to a local variable.  There may be cases where you simply don't want/need that information, but I imagine in the vast majority of cases you'd at least want to log the details somewhere.

Comment: In your case you might want to call something like `Logger.Log(e);` so you know that some exception occurred.

Comment: The real difference between `throw` and `throw e` is that `throw e` throws a brand new exception whereas `throw` simply allows the currently caught exception to continue percolating up the call stack. The stack trace is not "mangled" in any way. It generates a new stack trace with the `throw e` statement as the new point of origin for the error.

Comment: @Ferruccio It is mangled - you do not get a full stack trace anymore, but just a local one, which is far inferior compared to a full stacktrace. Seems like the catch bit is far less influencing than throw vs throw e then. Thanks for the replies everyone

Answer (score 3):

Well, the CLR doesn't have to create the variable. That is about it. The exception has already been instantiated, so no gain there. It is just the allocation of one extra variable.

I think that what the developer drove to removing that variable is the compiler warning:

> CS0168: The variable 'e' is declared but never used

Answer (score 2):

In Release mode, there is no difference in the IL generated by the compiler (no local variable is allocated for the exception in either case).

There is a slight difference when compiled in Debug mode (at least for me, compiling in VS 2017), where a local variable is allocated in the `catch (SomeException e)` case, but not in the `catch (SomeException)` case.

As such, the only compelling reason to remove the unused variable is to eliminate the compiler warning (which is a good enough reason for me).

Answer (score 0):

The difference being one allows you to have access to the `Exception` object as a variable, that way you can do different things e.g. a common approach would be logging.

So you could do something like

```
catch (FormatException e)
{
    _log.LogError(e);
}
```

Note, the above will log and swallow the exception, it all depends on the use-case of your code.